# How to list and delete terminfo?

Tags: terminfo

I have installed some custom `terminfo` with `tic` command. How do I list all `terminfo` in the database (e.g. with `infocmp`) and how to delete specific `terminfo`?

Here's my idea as of right now:

On Linux, system-wide `terminfo` database is located in `/lib/terminfo` (Debian), `/usr/share/terminfo` (Arch), and `/usr/share/lib/terminfo` (Solaris);

On macOS, system-wide `terminfo` database is located in `/usr/share/terminfo`;

User-defined `terminfo` database is in `~/.terminfo`.

For now I believe the `terminfo` database items could be altered by deleting the compiled items in those directories. So further questions are: Why are items `terminfo` organized in two hex digit directories (e.g. 31, 7a)? How are they organized? And if I write a new `terminfo` with `tic` into the database, but with an existent name, is the previous `terminfo` overwritten?

Comment: I think you did a little mistake there's no terminfo directory in `/user/share/lib`. I have terminfo in `/lib/terminfo`. Even, I am not sure if terminfo is in different directories in different linux distro...!

Comment: @Istiak You are partly right. AFAIK Solaris has terminfo in `/usr/share/lib`, while Arch in `/usr/share/terminfo`, and debian in `/lib/terminfo`. Maybe you are using a debian-derived distro? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Yes! I am using debian-derived distro.. **Kali**....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more than one question.  All of this is in the manual pages.

- *How do I list all terminfo in the database (e.g. with infocmp)*
  The ncurses infocmp program uses a compiled-in list of locations for terminal databases which can be overridden using the [**`TERMINFO_DIRS`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS) environment variable.  The [**`tic`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html#h3-OPTIONS) (and [**`infocmp`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html#h3-Other-Options)) `-D` option shows the list:

  ```
   -D     tells tic to print the database locations that it  knows  about,
          and exit.  The first location shown is the one to which it would
          write compiled terminal descriptions.  If tic  is  not  able  to
          find  a  writable  database  location  according  to  the  rules
          summarized above, it will print a diagnostic and  exit  with  an
          error rather than printing a list of database locations.
  ```
- ncurses also uses the [**`HOME`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-HOME) environment variable to  tell where tic may write a terminal description when you haven't permission to write in its preferred location.  There are problems with this feature (keeping it up to date, making it work with ***all*** versions of ncurses which may be installed on your machine, etc).
- *how to delete specific terminfo*
  There's no special command for deleting a terminal description because usually the whole terminal database at a given location is created as a unit (to handle cross-references).  Usually the terminal database is a collection of files, but it can be set up to use a hashed database.  For the former (collection of files), you can remove the file which infocmp prints in the comment at the beginning of the report.
- *Why are items terminfo organized in two hex digit directories (e.g. 31, 7a)?*
  Some of the terminal description names use uppercase characters, which would conflict with other names in lowercase when they're used as filenames on a filesystem that ignores case.  The default filesystem with MacOS ignores case.  The same is true for Cygwin.  When ncurses is configured for a given system, the configure script checks if the filesystem pays attention to case.  The [**`term`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html)  manual page is the place to read for this.

On occasion you'll see advice from other users (or from developers who are unfamiliar with the topic) advising you to *copy* a compiled terminal description from one machine to another.  That's poor advice because it doesn't take into account any of the preceding information.

Comment: Thank you sir, for taking time to answer my multiple questions, and for maintaining the database over the years!